# Howto JQuery append some DIV inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm needs this result after run code

```
  <form>
      <div class="row"><div class="col"><SELECT selectMark>...some options...</SELECT></div></div>
      <div class="row"><div class="col"><SELECT selectModel>...some options...</SELECT></div></div>
  </form>
```

My code is

```
  var form = $("<form></form>");
  var row = $("<div></div>").addClass("row");
  var col = $("<div></div>").addClass("col");

  var selectMark = $("<select></select>").attr("id", "mark"); 
  selectMark.append(markList);

  form.append(row).append(col).append(selectMark);

  var selectModel = $("<select></select>").attr("id", "model"); 
  selectModel .append(modelList);

  form.append(row).append(col).append(selectModel );
```

I get this HTML code in output

```
<form>
   <div class="row"></div>
   <div class="col"></div>
   <SELECT selectMark></SELECT>
   <SELECT selectModel></SELECT>
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: `<SELECT selectMark>` this is not a valid syntax. Also what is `markList` here?

Comment: I know, I write it for example - very long text.

Comment: markList and modelList - OPTIONS array for SELECTs

Answer (score 1):

The issue here jquery chain here refers to the first element always. That's why all of the elements are appended to `form` only. To nest them individually you will need to call them individually like:

```js
var form = $("<form></form>");
var row = $("<div></div>").addClass("row");
var col = $("<div></div>").addClass("col");

col.append("TEST")  // Add text node to col first
row.append(col)     // add col to row now
form.append(row)    // add the row to form now

$('body').append(form)  // and finally add the form to body or any parent element you need
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Form multiple appends you can use string instead like:

```js
var form = $("<form></form>");

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col">TEST1</div></div>')
form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col">TEST2</div></div>')
form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col">TEST3</div></div>')

$('body').append(form)
```

```css
form,.row,.col {margin:5px;padding:5px;border:1px solid #EEE}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

To happened `<select>` object you can use:

```js
var form = $("<form></form>");
var divs = '<div class="row"><div class="col"></div></div>';

var selectMark = $("<select/>").attr("id", "mark"); 
selectMark.append($("<option/>").attr("value", 1).text('--- Select Mark ---'));
form.append(divs).find('.row:last .col').append(selectMark)

var selectModel = $("<select/>").attr("id", "model");
selectModel.append($("<option/>").attr("value", 1).text('--- Select Model ---'));
form.append(divs).find('.row:last .col').append(selectModel)

$('body').append(form)
```

```css
form,.row,.col,select {margin:5px;padding:5px;border:1px solid #EEE}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to get a few of these. in our version, the variables after the first use will be changed.

        form.append(row).append(col).append("TEST");
        form.append(row).append(col).append("TEST2");
        form.append(row).append(col).append("TEST3");

Comment: Not getting what you mean here. Can you update your post with some example to explain it in a better way?

Comment: changed first question

Comment: I have added a solution for it.

Comment: Ok, in the code I dynamically create a SELECT.  `var selectMark = $("<select></select>").attr("id", "mark"); selectMark.append(markList);` How I can add object between DIV instead TEST?

Comment: Can you update your post with some example to explain it in a better way? Also, mention what is `markList` here.

Comment: yes, of course, changed. it’s my fault that I didn’t tell everything at once

Comment: I have added a solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, your variable still keep old div,

you should wrap your code to for loop, change `append` to `appendTo` as

```
 var form = $("<form></form>");

  for(var i = 1; i<=3; i++){
  var row = $("<div></div>").addClass("row");
  var col = $("<div></div>").addClass("col");
  col.append("TEST" + i);
  col.appendTo(row)
  row.appendTo(form);

  }
  form.appendTo('body');
```

```js
 var form = $("<form></form>");
 
  for(var i = 1; i<=3; i++){
  var row = $("<div></div>").addClass("row");
  var col = $("<div></div>").addClass("col");
  col.append("TEST" + i);
  col.appendTo(row)
  row.appendTo(form);
  
  }
  //form.append(row).append(col).append("TEST2");
  //form.append(row).append(col).append("TEST3");
  form.appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's right but I have different objects instead TESTs. And wanted to save variables unchanged and use it like templates.  in the code I dynamically create a SELECT. `var selectMark = $("<select></select>").attr("id", "mark"); selectMark.append(markList);` How I can add object between DIV instead TEST?

Answer (score 1):

form.append(row).append(col).append("TEST")
will append row, followed by col, followed by "TEST" to the form element as jQuery chaining allows you to run multiple jQuery methods **on the same element(s)**. Since you want to nest these elements individually you will need to call the append method for each of them. One way to accomplish this is like so:

```
col.append("TEST");
row.append(col).appendTo(form); // appendTo declares the element you want to append the result of the previous methods to.
$('body').append(form);
```